# Create ember-data record outside of store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am very new to Emberjs.

I would like to create a temporary instance of a model (Customer) for use in my "customer.create" route. However I don't want it to be added to the store. Is there a way to do this?

Currently I am doing this:

```
model: function(){
    return {
        firstName:'', lastName:'', title: ''
    };
},
```

but I would like to use methods within the actual model.

Comment: Why don't you want it added to the store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually just return javascript objects in the model hook. I watched this video on using Ember without ember-data: [ember without ember-data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7twifrxOTQY) so one option could be to create a *object* with the appropriate schema then it will be usable as your model but wont be in the store until you create a record in the store and set the values accordingly.

something like:

```
model: function() {
  return { firstname: '', lastname: '', title: ''};
}
```

then the object is accessible in your templates as the model but not in the store.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up going with this.